# Automating MathO with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can use VBA to insert an equation into a MS Word document using the Equation Tool third party software which comes bundled with it. The problem comes when I want to exit the equation edior and write ordinary MS Word text. This has to be automated using VBA. Here is the VBA code I use to insert the code:

```
Set objRange = Selection.Range
Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
Selection.TypeText s
Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
objEq.Type = wdOMathInline
objEq.BuildUp
```

Let me make the problem clearer: I would like to have the equation editor's text inside a paragraph of ordinary text, just as I would like to be able to have **bold text** inside a paragraph of plain text, as in this paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I had some success using `Selection.TypeParagraph` to escape from the equation editor:

```
Set objRange = Selection.Range
Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
Selection.TypeText "Equation Text"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.TypeText "Regular Text"
Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
objEq.Type = wdOMathInline
objEq.BuildUp
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I tried using the Range, but with no success. 

    Sub PrintMath(s As String)
    Dim charStart As Integer
    Dim charEnd As Integer
    Dim objRange As Range
    charStart = ActiveDocument.Characters.Count
    charEnd = charStart + Len(s)
    Set objRange = ActiveDocument.Range(charStart, charEnd)
    Set objRange = Selection.Range
    Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)
    Selection.TypeText s
    Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
    objEq.Type = wdOMathInline
    objEq.BuildUp
     End Sub

Comment: It looks like what you're trying to do is insert the formula at the end of the document. If that's the case, just use `Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory` to place the cursor and the end. Then proceed with the code above. If you're looking to do something more than that, let me know.